# Generate id and parent values by verifying its date range comes under before date values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to give id and parent values in the pandas dataframe. If Not-in-family's date range comes under Husband then its id is A-1.1 otherwise A-2 and its parent is before record's id.

```
>>>mydf
            name    start_date   end_date      id  parent
0       Total data 2020-01-01 2021-03-18  A-Root    None
1          Husband 2020-01-01 2021-03-15     A-1  A-Root
2    Not-in-family 2020-01-02 2021-03-18       -       -
3        Unmarried 2020-01-04 2021-03-04       -       -
4             Wife 2020-01-10 2021-03-17       -       -
5        Own-child 2020-01-11 2021-03-16       -       -
```

Expected output is

```
              name start_date   end_date      id  parent
0       Total data 2020-01-01 2021-03-18  A-Root    None
1          Husband 2020-01-01 2021-03-15     A-1  A-Root
2    Not-in-family 2020-01-02 2021-03-18     A-2  A-Root
3        Own-child 2020-01-11 2021-03-16   A-2.1     A-2
4        Unmarried 2020-01-04 2021-03-04   A-1.1     A-1
5             Wife 2020-01-10 2021-03-17     A-3     A-2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe fill rows with values based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68926636/dataframe-fill-rows-with-values-based-on-condition)

Comment: I don't understand the description of the conditions for the classification you require. Could you maybe rephrase, assuming we have no idea how to read your table?